# Javascript array with keys

Tags: javascript

I was playing around with regex in JS today and came across a data structure I've never seen before: an array where some of the entries have keys. A method which returns such a data structure is the regex [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) function. Here's an example:

```
    var re = /SESSID=\w+=;/;
    var test = 'SESSID=aaaa=;fjsdfjd';
    var arr = test.match(re);
    console.log(arr);  // ["SESSID=aaaa=;", index: 0, input: "SESSID=aaaa=;fjsdfjd"]
    console.log(arr[0]);  // SESSID=aaaa=;
    console.log(arr['index']);  // 0
    console.log(arr['input']);  // SESSID=aaaa=;fjsdfjd
```

What's going on here?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#Description

Comment: Be aware that adding non-index properties to arrays might make implementations switch the underlying data structure to a hash table (or whatever they use for normal objects). So better don't do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays are just objects. They can have any sort of properties.

The properties whose names are numeric strings are special, because they're bound up in the semantics of the "length" property, but otherwise they're just plain properties too.

I should note that while all of the above is true, there are things to know when adding non-numeric properties to an array. Non-numeric properties do not affect the "length" value, so you can't use `.length` to see how many there are. More important, non-numeric properties are not included in the output when an array is serialized with `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: Awesome - thanks! How can I create such an object myself? If I try `var test = ['zero', one: 'one'];`, I get an `Unexpected token :` error.

Comment: @kcstricks you create the array, and then add properties to it just as you would a plain object. You can't do it with the array initializer syntax however.